# deploySandboxInstance() error while creating a sandbox instance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

We are performing HA InnoDb in Mysql. For that we need 3 instance to perform failover.
While running this query in msql-js we got an error of invalid object member.

Query - dba.deploySandboxInstance(3310);
Error - Invalid object member deploySanboxInstance (AttributeError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear: Invalid object member deploySanboxInstance (AttributeError)

The function is named "deploySandboxInstance".

Note that sandboxes are **not** suitable for production environments and should be used for testing purposes only.

Please read the user guide as it contains all the information you're looking for:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-userguide.html